# phonegap xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4.3

Yesterday I started to develop with Phonegap.
I downloaded phonegap and xCode 4.3 from the Mac App Store.

When I try to install phonegap it says: no iOS SDK installed.
I searched the web but couldn't find any solution.

Can someone tell what I need to do?

Thanks

**EDIT 2**

Alright, phonegap 1.5 is released today and it works with Xcode 4.3. Sweet :)

***EDIT**
Found a work-a-round
https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaInstaller/CordovaInstaller.pmdoc/index.xml#L36-47*

Comment: Can you tell us where Xcode is installed (whole path)

Comment: Right in the application folder. /Application

Comment: yeah found the icon. but what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap wasn't ready for Apple's latest Xcode surprise, that being the removal of the traditional `/Developer` and `SDK` directories.

You'll have to go back to Xcode 4.2 or wait a few weeks for PhoneGap 1.5 or 1.6.

[This Phonegap Discussion group thread here](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/e201826bfa6f39bd) has another suggestion:  a patch that takes the SDK check out of the PhoneGap installer (see [these highlighted lines in GitHub](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaInstaller/CordovaInstaller.pmdoc/index.xml%23L36-47&usg=AFQjCNHtSGNrUwY14F0IePeIz967Nelsdg))

Comment: Ok. Maybe I'll have to do that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Alright, phonegap 1.5 is released today and it works with Xcode 4.3. Sweet :)

Answer (score 2):

Patching and building PhoneGap installer didn't work for me. :(

Just create Xcode and iOS SDK directories to skip the requirements part.

```
sudo mkdir -p /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
sudo mkdir -p /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
```

And install with the package from http://phonegap.com/